# React - Collect data in a react form - react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I want to collect all the data from a form

I'm using react hooks. From my understanding of hooks, I just need to use a set to update a variable. Currently this doesn't work for me.

I want to collect all the information, then console.log it within my onSubmit form for my next step

I created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-lake-lmnr7) with the working code as well

Any explanation is appreciated

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState({
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    inputField: "",
    platformToSearch: ""
  });
  const { handleSubmit, register, reset, control } = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const [selectedStartDate, setSelectedStartDate] = useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );
  const [selectedEndDate, setSelectedEndDate] = useState(
    new Date("2014-20-18T21:11:54")
  );

  /*dropdown for social platforms*/
  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  // const myRef = useRef(null);

  const showPlatformOptions = () => {
    if (!expanded) {
      setExpanded(true);
    } else {
      setExpanded(false);
    }
  };

  const handlePlatformQueryChange = event => {
    if (event.target.checked && !query.includes(event.target.value)) {
      setQuery([...query, event.target.value]);
    } else if (!event.target.checked && query.includes(event.target.value)) {
      setQuery(query.filter(q => q !== event.target.value));
    }
    setSearchData({ ...searchData.platformToSearch, query });
  };

  const handleStartDateChange = date => {
    //console.log("Selected start date:", date._d)
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   setSearchData(...searchData.startDate, date._d);
    // }, [searchData]);
    setSearchData(...searchData.startDate, date._d);
    setSelectedStartDate(date._d);
  };
  const handleEndDateChange = date => {
    //console.log("Selected end date:", date)
    setSearchData(...searchData.endDate, date._d);
    setSelectedEndDate(date._d);
  };

  const onSubmit = data => {
    // How should this be
    //updated to store all the slected items from the form

    console.log("Collected Data:", searchData);
    console.log("searchData:", searchData);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    reset(defaultValues);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => onSubmit(data))}>
        <div className="flex">
          <SelectSocialPlatform
            query={query}
            expanded={expanded}
            onClick={showPlatformOptions}
            onChange={handlePlatformQueryChange}
          />
          <Calendar
            name="StartDate"
            label="START DATE"
            value={selectedStartDate}
            onChange={handleStartDateChange}
          />
          <Calendar
            name="EndDate"
            label="END DATE"
            value={selectedEndDate}
            onChange={handleEndDateChange}
          />

          <InputField
            name="inputField"
            placeholder="Search by keywords, #hashtags, or @socialmediahandles"
            refs={register}
            className="border-blue-200 border rounded w-full h-20 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          />

          <SearchButton
            className="bg-blue-800 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded h-20 w-40"
            text="Search"
            onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            type="submit"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: i didn't realize you are using a third party library, can you try `handleSubmit(onSubmit)`

Comment: I get an error when trying to run in sandbox:

`TypeError
Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
    at _nonIterableSpread (https://lmnr7.csb.app/node_modules/
babel/runtime/helpers/nonIterableSpread.js:2:9
    at _toConsumableArray (https://lmnr7.csb.app/node_modules/
babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js:8:60
handleInputField
/src/app.jsx:35:21`

... 

`33 |   //console.log("Selected end date:", date)
  34 |   setInputField(event.target.value);
> 35 |   setSearchData(...searchData.inputField, inputField);
     |                   ^
  36 | };`
...

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin I went ahead and fixed that error

Comment: @windmaomao you provide a example